# Moviepy return error on CompositeVideoClip = TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am trying to composite a '.mp4' video and 'text' using VideoFileClip and TextClip respectively by appending them to a variable 'clip_list'.

If I try to print 'clip_list' on console it logs:

```
[<moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip.VideoFileClip object at 0x7f3d1da98208>,
 <moviepy.video.VideoClip.TextClip object at 0x7f3d20699a20>]
```

Now using CompositeVideoClip on clip_list gives me following error.

[image]

Any help here? I am using:

> Python 3.7.3 moviepy==1.0.2 numpy==1.18.3

Answer (score 0):

can you please share your actual code that produces the output and the errors. It's very hard to reproduce those errors without having the actual code.